# Springboot + thymeleaf can't find any template except home + template mapping not working

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, thymeleaf

I'm using springboot + thymeleaf and have just started setting up the project. 
At first this worked fine, showing my home page and account page, but I must've changed something somewhere because now it will only show home.

weird stuff 1: It takes the template home from the resources/templates folder, although I've configured it to not do that. My guess is it doesn't use the configuration.

weird stuff 2: It only finds the home template, not the account template.

What do I need to change to get this working again?

**Configuration class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("applikaasie.domein")
public class startApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(startApp.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {
      ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
      viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
      return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean 
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine(TemplateResolver templateResolver) {
      SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
      templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
      return templateEngine;
    }
    @Bean
    public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
      TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
      templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates");
      templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
      templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
      System.out.println("templateResolver");
      return templateResolver;

    }
}
```

**Account class:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="account")
public class AccountController {

  @RequestMapping(value="/", method=GET)
  public String greeting() {
    return "home";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/accounts", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String accountList(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute(accountRepository.getAllAccounts());
    return "accounts";
  }
}
```

**Directory structure:**

```
/resources
  /templates
    account.html
    home.html
/webapp
  /WEB-INF
    /templates
      account.html
      home.html
```

---

**UPDATE**

Resetting the computer fixed this. I guess something in memory was wrong.

Comment: change  return "accounts" to "account"

Comment: thanks, that didn't fix the problem but did get me closer :)